# Choicefield empty string and null

Tags: python, html, django

I have Django a model that has a different meaning between a null value and a blank value. When I create a choicefield with the following `CHOICES`:

```
CHOICES = [
    (None, 'Null'),
    ('', 'Blank'),
    ('foo', 'Foo'),
    ('bar', 'Bar')
]
```

The admin form generates this:

```
<select name='my_field'>
  <option value>Null</option>
  <option value>Blank</option>
  <option value='foo'>Foo</option>
  <option value='bar'>Bar</option>
</select>
```

So that when you submit the form with "blank" selected, the database saves the `null` value. Is there a way to make Django distinguish within the admin form blank from null?

Edit:

for more context here is the existing code I am working with simplified some:

```
class CustomChoiceField(models.CharField):
    FIELD_SETTINGS = {
        'null': True,
        'blank': True,
        'max_length': 5,
        'choices': [
            (None, 'Null'),
            ('', 'Blank'),
            ('foo', 'Foo'),
            ('bar', 'Bar')
        ]
    }


class MyModel(BaseModel):
    my_field = CustomChoiceField('label')
```

Comment: Can you add the values of fields in the model? (You can get them in clean method of your model)

Comment: The docs appear to say that either None or a blank string will produce the same behavior. Last paragraph: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#choices

Comment: What happens when you put those 4 choices into their own model and then FK to it and display them that way?

Comment: It seems you are trying to create new model fields via forms. I strongly discourage the parametric definition of new fields, as they will need migrations. Anyway, if you want  to save both null and blank values, I suggest creating string variables named 'null' and 'blank' and then convert them during instance creation and retrieval.

Comment: The issue was that someone looked at the instance of the model which was supposed to have `Blank` as the value in the Admin view. but the way the admin was rendered displayed `Null`, and even when they put the value to `Blank` and hit save, it changed the value in the database to `null`. Basically, I am looking for a way to keep people from breaking the Model when they use Admin View.

Comment: @jfundako, propably has what would have been the right desision from the start. But basically not sure I could get that change approved this late in the game.